# iPod shuffle not charging

Tags: ipod, charging

My iPod has been dead for about 8 months. I plugged the charger into a PC and its not blinking and there's actually no light at all. How long will it take for it to start again? I really need help and don't know how long it will take.

Comment: Have you tried with its proper charger? Use one you know works for other  devices & leave it overnight to test.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how depleted it is, it may not charge at all since the battery protection circuit could be completely offline and block power in that mode, effectively disabling all power. I came across this a few times and I fixed it by opening the device and applying regulated power directly to bypass this issue and get the controllers working so it could charge itself and get back into normal working condition.

In your case, if it was completely empty and then stored for 8 months, it is possible that this is the situation you're in.  Normally, a small leakage current still flows which allows the charging controller to turn on and make the device start working, but that does not always work. Using a proper charger helps if the device is built to recover only when applied the correct voltage with enough amps.